# How to see Django logging in production

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm deploying a Django project in production with, obviously,  `DEBUG=False`. How can I see all Django logs like in development environment?

I've configured a logger but I'm only able to see custom logs in a file. Where are the default ones?

Answer (score 8):

You have to configure the logger for the `django` module for it to route records to file. Example:

```
LOGGING = {                                                                                                                 
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'server.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
        },
    },
}
```

Consult [list of django loggers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#id3) to see what other loggers Django offers.

Comment: With this config, will I see all the logs (like in dev terminal) in a file?

Comment: If you set the `level` to `DEBUG` in logger/handler sections of the config dict, then you will see everything you see in the dev console and even more (db queries etc). However, using the debug level in production is discouraged because it's a potential leakage of internal data - it's not far from using `DEBUG = True` in prod.

Comment: @matthew it belongs into your settings module.

Comment: @hoefling thanks, can you please add a link on where did you find this "format" in a way =? :) Thanks man I appreciated it.

Comment: @matthew you mean adding it to the answer? The page you referenced contains several config examples (check out the [Examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#examples) section); for the general specification of logging dict config, here is the page from the python docs: [Configuration dictionary schema](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema)

Comment: @hoefling yes sir :) They are very helpful these links to understand the dictionary structure

Comment: @matthew aren't you eligible to edit the posts? You can edit the answer and I'll approve it.